# Using Mock in python for DynamoDB and Table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mocking

I want to test my python function which work is to extract all the data from the dynamoDB table

```
import boto3
import json
import constant as const
def connection():
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('file')
    response = table.scan()['Items']
    return response
```

And I am testing my above code using unit test. The code that I have written is given below

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import retrive
import constant
import boto3
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('boto3.resource')
    @mock.patch('boto3.resource.Table')
    @mock.patch('table.scan')
    def test_fetch_db_data(self, mock_boto3,mock_dynamo,mock_table):
        mock_boto3.return_value()
        mock_dynamo.return_value()
        mock_table = {'Items':'key'}
        result = retrive.connection()
        self.assertEqual('key', result)
```

but this give me an error i.e ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'table'

Comment: Where is your `table` coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this answer: [How to mock AWS DynamoDB service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711004/how-to-mock-aws-dynamodb-service).

It's also possible to do what you try to do, but it will look something like:

`@mock.patch('botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call', new=mock_function)`

It is a more complicated way to do things than `moto` since you need to define `mock_function` which will generate mocked client responses.